# How to Create a new array with selected element from existing array in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'am new to Angular and TypeScript, i'am trying to implement this one but i couldn't make it possible.

My question is i have an array with multiple nested arrays. every nested array has 'id' value. i need get all the nested array 'id' values and store those values to the new array.

this is what i have right now

```
[parentArray]
  0: nestedArray
     count: 0
     no: null
     level: null
     id: 1
  1: nestedArray
     count: 0
     no: null
     level: null
     id: 22
  2: nestedArray
     count: 0
     no: null
     level: null
     id: 34
```

I want an array like this, example - idInformation = [1,22,34].

I tried with filter but it gives all the values, i don't know exactly how to do this in TypeScript. please help me to get this or any help also appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about typescript nor about angular, you should get familiar with basic javascript.

And looking at your data sample I suppose you have array of objects, not array of arrays.

```
const ids = array.map(v => v.id);
```